# Strong Parameters #require Convention in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conventions, strong-parameters, rails-api

I understand how the [#require](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) method works, but why/when should it be used. Is using `require` a best practice and why?

At least for simple controllers and parameters, `require` seems pointless.

**For example:**

Given these params

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
  person: {
    name: "Francesco",
    age:  22,
    role: "admin"
  }
})

permitted = params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)

----

params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
  name: "Francesco",
  age:  22,
  role: "admin"
})

permitted = params.permit(:name, :age)
```

Whether I use `require` or not the permitted object is the same:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Francesco", "age"=>22} permitted: true>
```

And I can mass assign with or without `require(:person)`.

*This is not a question about ParamsWrapper

Comment: What you're really asking is why take parameters as `person: { name: "Francesco", age:  22, role: "admin" }`. Why not just use `{ name: "Francesco", age:  22, role: "admin" }`? Consider what happens when you need to send a parameter which is not a person attribute.

Comment: That makes sense, or if I need to create another object from a different model class. I would want to extract just the params I need to create the model. 

Is it a convention or best practice to do add `require` regardless of whether the params has a parameter that is not an attribute? If so, why?

Comment: I think you have it backwards. `params.require(:person)` says there must be a key of `person` in the params. The best practice is to group your parameters by model like `person: { ... }`. It's a Rails convention and how [form helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects) work. I think looking at form helpers will clarify a lot.